# Access FTP sever from android app

Tags: android, ftp, android-permissions

I can't access "ftp server in PC" from "android app" to download file, I used wireless connection.

```
public void FTP_Download(){

            String server = "192.168.1.135";
            int port = 21;
            String user = "pc1";
            String pass = "1551";

            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

            try {

                ftpClient.connect(server, port);
                ftpClient.login(user, pass);
                ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "download starting.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // APPROACH #1: using retrieveFile(String, OutputStream)
                String remoteFile1 = "i.xml";
                File downloadFile1 = new File("sdcard/i.xml");

                OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
                boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
                outputStream1.close();

                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File #1 has been downloaded successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                        ftpClient.logout();
                        ftpClient.disconnect();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }





}
```

I added internet permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Note: I tested app in emulator on PC and all things was OK.

When I tried to access FTP from default browser I can't, but I can from firefox.

any help please

Comment: Sanity check: By "wireless connection" you mean the same WiFi network, to which your PC is connected?

Comment: You run this on UI thread, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue. If it worked on the emulator and not on the device, there's probably a firewall in your way, or your network isn't allowing the connection because for some reason it's not secure enough. Also make sure your FTP server allows connections from your username and password.

Comment: Thanks for all
the problem was in firewall, I switched it off, so I could access to server

thank you @GraphicsMuncher :)

Comment: @SWE Glad that works. Although if you can, try to configure your firewall to allow your connections rather than shutting it off completely.

Comment: I have new a problem, I created my app to android 2.3.3, and it work OK, but it didn't work on android 4, I tried to rebuild for android 4, but same thing, I can't to connect to server.

Comment: If you have a new problem, best to ask a new question. Comments are not a good place for that.